# Build Current Working Set Only in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to setup Eclipse so that, when I am switched between working sets, only that working set is automatically built and, additionally, the Problems/Tasks/etc views only show information from projects contained in the current working set?  I searched around and couldn't find anything (other than setting up these filters manually).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the only option is to close projects from other working sets. If you have Working Sets shown as top elements in Package Explorer view you can select working set nodes and call Close or Open Project action from the popup menu.

Comment: Shame that this is the answer (no offense).  It would be very useful to have Eclipse work only on the working sets rather than having to configure it manually all the time.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow it never bothered me. The Eclipse's incremental compiler is fast enough, so most of the time it is not noticeable even on a large workspace. Though 3rd party tools can make it much worse.

Comment: Better: If you have Working Sets shown as top elements in Package Explorer view you can select working set nodes, right-click and select "Build Projects" which builds all projects in the working set. You can also assign a key binding to that action.

Answer (score 3):

I notice that if you disable "build automatically" under the "project" menu, you can then select which working sets to include in your build (project -> build working set -> select working set). I don't think this is the "automatic" build behavior you are looking for though....  also, for the problems view, I thought this stack overflow answer was pretty solid.

[Best Practices for Eclipse's Problems View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156745/best-practices-for-eclipses-problems-view)

Comment: This is the best answer for me, because I don't like the "build automatically"

Answer (score 0):

Another way to tackle this issue is by using tasks with **[Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/)**

[image]

Without a repository, a local task is attached to a workspace.
For each task you can attach a **Context** - describes the resources that are most relevant to the task.

Comment: Mylyn is a neat tool, but it is not going to prevent Eclipse from building resources out of the current task context.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Working Sets shown as top elements in Package Explorer view you can select working set nodes, right-click and select "Build Projects" which builds all projects in the working set. You can also assign a key binding to that action.