# Eclipse won't check for errors in my code (Java EE)

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, jakarta-ee

I have been trying to use Spring in my Java EE projects and while everything will compile just fine for some reason Eclipse just refuses to do any sort of live error checking like it normally does. you know like underlining a line of code that is totally wrong for ex:

```
System.BananaBoat.SetSail();
```

Obviously this class doesn't exist but Eclipse isn't throwing any sort of error at all. It just lets me do it. Is there something I need to enable to make sure that this is getting tested? Is this related to the incremental compiler?

Any insight on this would be great. Feels like being back in the stone age without this.

Comment: Does it happen on all of your Java files?  And are you sure that they're all on the build path - i.e. they are in a folder designated as a source folder, and aren't excluded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the project has any problems in the "problems" fast view. Sometimes, Eclipse refuses to build automatically if there is a problem such as a cyclic module dependency, or some required .class file being referenced indirectly.

Here are some links:
[Eclipse Problems View not showing Errors anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253357/eclipse-problems-view-not-showing-errors-anymore) 
[Best Practices for Eclipse's Problems View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156745/best-practices-for-eclipses-problems-view) 
http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cprbview.htm

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the automatic build isn't turned off.

Comment: Under Project "Build Automatically" is checked, so it seems like it is. This project requires Ant to actually compose it into a war file but still I would think it would be checking these things

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer somewhere else.. Anywho, make sure your files are under the "src" file under your project, I had mine in another folder, for some reason eclipse will refuse to error-check in a place other than the src folder.