# The red ! mark after the build in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, build

I'm trying to build eclipse source base in eclipse. After the build is done I have yellow ! mark, red ! mark, and red X mark.

[image]

I see that yellow mark as a waring, and red X mark as an error. However, I'm not sure what is the red ! mark is for? I opened the project, but I see nothing no errors inside the project files.

[image]

Comment: Does the tooltip show anything useful?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about the tooltip you mentioned, but I have 131,398 errors. I don't know how to map between the "red ! mark" and error descriptions.

Comment: I mean, what shows up when you hover the icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red ! usually means that there's an error with the project configuration.  The most common error is a missing jar.

If you think everything is in place and this is the first time you've tried to build this code, it could be that you haven't enabled a pre-req. Try creating a new Eclipse plugin to enable the eclipse plugin libraries, for example.  The Problems view will tell you which classes can't be found.  From that you can infer the missing jars and from that you can infer the pre-reqs to enable.

Answer (score 2):

You can find information about these errors in `Problems` View.

EDIT
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/161493/1506264) can help you to filter out unnecessary stuff from `Problems` View and to observe errors about your specific packages.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to bellum and Chris, I could setup to show only the errors and projects for the project that I click on.

[image]

Now I see there are 2 errors to cause the "red !" for the project.

[image]